# Replace values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array a and an array b, which look like this:

```
a = np.array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
              [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
              [ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
b = np.array([[2, 3, 4, 5],[2,3,4,5]])
```

Now I want to replace the second until fifth value of a with b in the rows, where the first element is equals to 1. Desired output:

```
a = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
              [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
              [ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I've tried `a[a[:,0] == 1][:,1:] = b`, but it still gives me

```
a = np.array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
              [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
              [ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try : `a[a[:,0] == 1,1:] = b`. That chaining isn't working on the original array, but on a copy.

Comment: Many thanks. Yep, just figured it out. Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Feel free to write up your answer post. Good to share with the community things you have learnt in the process.